# How to split my chat commands into differents files?

Tags: node.js, architecture, discord.js

I'm creating a basic **nodejs based chatbot** for discord using discordjs.
In my main script, when a 'message' event is sent, the bot checks if the message match with a specific command and, in this case call it. The functions corresponding to these commands are in methods in a "TextCommand" class, inported in the main script, but the TextCommand file is getting too big I think...

I tried to split each command in one file and export it, but I can't import it as methods into TextCommand class.

index.js

```js
const TextCommand = require('./src/commands.js');

client.on('message', (msg) => {
  if (!msg.author.bot) {
    let command;
    let reg;
    let prefix;

    if (msg.guild != undefined){   // Guild commands
      db.query(`SELECT prefix FROM guilds WHERE discord_id=${msg.guild.id};`, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        prefix = result[0].prefix
        command = new TextCommand(prefix, msg)
        reg = new RegExp('^' + prefix, 'i')

        if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + 'help')) {
          command.help();

        } else if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + 'ping')) {
          command.ping();

        } else if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + 'search')) {
          command.search();
```

TextCommand file

```js
module.exports = class TextCommand {
  constructor(prefix, msg){
    this.message = msg;
    this.prefix = prefix;
  }

  ping(){
    this.message.channel.send('pong !');
  }

  search(){
    let search = this.message.content.slice(this.prefix.length + 'search '.length).replace(/ /g, '+');
    this.message.channel.send(`http://google.com/search?q=${search}`);
  }
```

I do not understand how to use class extands... but maybe it's a part of the solution, **I would include my functions into TextCommands just wrinting them somewhere else** (and export it)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a class to hold every command you own, try [exporting](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/nodejs-module-exports) commands.

For instance, in the ready event, you'll want to search the `commands` folder for command files, which may follow the format of `<command name>.js`, so a command `!foo` would be `foo.js` in the folder `commands`.
To find all the files in the `commands` folder:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const readdir = promisify(require('fs').readdir);

client.commands = new Map();

client.on('ready', async () => {
  readdir('./commands/', (error, files) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    files.forEach(file => {
      if (!file.endsWith('.js')) return; // make sure the file is what you are looking for
      try {
        const properties = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        client.commands.set(properties.help.name, properties);
      } catch (err) {
        throw err;
      }  
    });
  }
});
```

This basically defines a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), extended from the [`client` object](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client) called `client.commands`. This map will contain the command properties, which is used to run the command later. The `readdir` reads the directory of `./commands/` for any file (using the [module `fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system)), and tries to filter them so they are only javascript files (ending with `.js`), and then adds the commands to the map with its properties.

Later, on the `message` event, you'll want to test to see if the message content is the command that you have coded:

```
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (!message.guild) return; // exit if the message does not have a guild
  if (message.author.bot) return; // exit if the message author is a bot
  // ... your database code to get the prefix ...

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g).call(Function.prototype.call, String.prototype.trim);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  const cmd = client.commands.get(command);
  if (!cmd) return; // the message is not a command we know of
  cmd.run(client, message, args); // run the command with client object, message object and args array
});
```

This code does the basic checks, to make sure the bot is only responding to a user in a guild channel (you may also want to check if the message is from Discord: [`message.system`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=system)).
After, it'll separate the content after the prefix into an array, splitting on a space, and then trimming every element of leading and trailing white space.
It'll then assign the first element of the `args` array to the constant command, to then be checked if that command exists in our map.
If it does, it'll `run` the command (apart of the `module.exports`), passing along the client object, message object, and the arguments array.

Finally, in a command file, such as `foo.js`, you'll need to have some important code to make sure the bot registers said the file is a command we want to run. This is:

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
// ... command logic
message.channel.send('Hello!');
};

module.exports.help = {
  name: 'foo'
};
```

This is the basic layout of the command file the system is able to read. The first line exports the `run` process of the command, which is an async function. It also exports the `help` object, which includes the name of the command. It's best that this is the same as the file name since this `name` is what the command is responding to.

In my opinion, this is a better method than creating the class holding all the commands, but I'll keep an open mind!